# Authorize.net PHP Session Variables Being Erased

Tags: php, session, authorize.net

I am having an issue with transfering PHP session variables after a payment is processed by my payment gateway. I have a payment page hosted on my server which submits to an SSL page to be processed on another domain (authorize.net).

The payment gateway then returns a variable to indicate whether or not the payment was a success. However, on some browsers the session variables don't carry through after the domain redirect, so I can't update the user's info in the database to reflect the purchase. What could be a cause of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Use [Silent Post](http://www.johnconde.net/blog/all-about-authorize-nets-silent-post/). Silent Post is Authorize.Net's equivalent of Paypal's IPN. Silent Post will allow you to retrieve the information from each transaction "in the background" so you can update your database accordingly. [Implementing it in PHP is easy to do](http://www.johnconde.net/blog/handling-authorize-net-silent-post-with-php/). (*Disclaimer, I wrote broke articles*)
2. You can pass the session ID as a hidden field to the payment page and then when the user is redirected back to your site you can restart the session by passing it as a parameter to [`session_id()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) which will restart the session.